# Set file permissions for mysqldump output

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, cron, mysql, chmod

I have a daily backup made that goes into my Dropbox folder. The file won't sync to could because of its default permission.

Can I control the permissions of the .sql.gz that comes from the "mysqldump" process?
Alternatively, can I change file permissions from `crontab chmod` does not seem to work.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

yes. Ofcourse you can change the permission through crontab

In crontab file you can add one more line next to your mysqldump creation as below:

```
* * * * * chmod 755 <mysqldump name>
```

[since i dont know the time of scheduling the job  you can change the parameters as per your requirement]

Or if you are worried about the time lag for changing permission and dumping file, you make a simple shell script for dumping mysqldump with next line to chmod command. Hence, instead of calling mysqldump, you can call that shell script which will do mysqldump creation and change the permission too.

Answer (score 4):

Default permissions of files are controlled by [umask](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umask). You need to set umask before running mysqldump.

For example, replace `mysqldump [...] | gzip > dump.sql.gz` with `umask 022; mysqldump [...] | gzip > dump.sql.gz`. Then the resulting file will be readable by all users.